# Add 'delete' button to php results table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I outputted the results of a MySQL table to an HTML table, I'm trying to add a Delete button to remove the user but it doesn't work.

HTML form code:

```
<?php 
        $response = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM users');
        $i = 1;
        while ($datas = $response->fetch()) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $datas['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $datas['last_name']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <form action="_delete.php?id=<?php echo $datas['id']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $datas['id'];?>">
            <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit" value="X">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my _delete.php :

```
<?php
try
{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>

<?php
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1";

//sends the query
mysql_query ($query);

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { 
?>

   <strong>User Has Been Deleted</strong>

<?php
 } else { 
?>

   <strong>Deletion Failed</strong>

<?php
} 
?>
```

My result url is good `/_delete.php?id=13` but Delete script isn't.

I have this error: `Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future`

Any idea?

Comment: I hate to ask but did you already mysql_connect() to the DB?

Comment: Yes I include it before my code, <?php include("../_database.php");?>

Comment: `$datas` is populated from where? and your `_delete.php?id` is a GET method, not POST. In any which case, check for errors via php and the query. Your "Deletion Failed" isn't helping you.

Comment: @Fred I update my code, php error is: `Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future`

Answer (score 0):

Your messing around with GET and POST params. You defined a get param named `id` containing your id and a post param named `name` containing also your id.

But currently you are trying to access the get param with `$_POST` (which contains only post params).

To solve your problem, you should use `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['name']`.

In each way, keep in mind to protect you input from sql injections. Currently the user could pass anything else as well. A simple cast to an int, would be enough.

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I try with `$id = $_GET['id'];` and `$id =$_POST['name'];` but same error.

Comment: I just update my code with your method and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have incoporated a few suggestions in my answer, try and see if it works.
Create a connection, then get the ID using $_GET instead of $_POST.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpassword","dbname");

if($con==false){
    die("ERROR:Could not connect.". mysqli_connect_error());

}
 else{
$id=$_GET['id']
 $query = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";

 //sends the query
 mysql_query ($con,$query);

 if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) { 
 ?>

  <strong>User Has Been Deleted</strong>

<?php
} else { 
?>

  <strong>Deletion Failed</strong>

<?php
} 
}
?>
```